# MongoDB y Python, enrutar la pagina de un usuario

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

estoy haciendo el inicio de sesion para una web. Por ahora es algo básico, solo recojo informacion de un formulario HTML y creo una instancia en la base de datos. Mi problema es que quiero que la ruta sea *localhost:5000/user/'id'*, siendo id el identificador que se almacena en la base de datos tras crear el usuario (un ObjectId). Dejo el codigo a continuacion:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo, ObjectId
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI']='mongodb://localhost/iWebGrafitis'
mongo = PyMongo(app)

db = mongo.db.Users

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("inicioSesion.html")

@app.route('/user/<id>', methods=["POST"])
def createUser(methods=['POST']):
    nombre = request.form.get("name")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    id = db.insert_one({
        "name": nombre,
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    })

    return render_template("usuario.html", nombre=nombre)
```

Al compilar, el error que me sale es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT Problema solucionado**
Este es el código con la solución. Lo que hice fue redirigir del método POST a otro GET. Imagino que se puede hacer todo en un mismo método pero no caigo en cómo.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo, ObjectId
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI']='mongodb://localhost/iWebGrafitis'
mongo = PyMongo(app)

db = mongo.db.Users

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("inicioSesion.html")

@app.route('/user', methods=["POST"])
def createUser():
    nombre = request.form.get("name")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    result = db.insert_one({
        "name": nombre,
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    })

    #return render_template("usuario.html", nombre=nombre, id=result.inserted_id)
    return redirect(url_for('findUser', id=result.inserted_id))

@app.route('/user/<id>', methods=["GET"])
def findUser(id):
    user = db.find_one({"_id" : ObjectId(id)})
    return render_template("usuario.html", nombre=user.get('name'), id=user.get('_id'))
```

Comment: No agregues **Solucionado** a tu pregunta, en vez de eso, puedes redactar tu propia respuesta en el área de respuestas. Incluso puedes luego de un tiempo (24 horas) aceptar tu propia respuesta como válida. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear una ruta con un [parámetro dinámico](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/?highlight=dynamic%20parameters#variable-rules) o componente dinámico en la ruta. Sin embargo al intentar crear dicha ruta, obtenemos el siguiente mensaje de error:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'createUser'. Did you forget tu especify values ['id']?

El cual indica que nos hemos olvidado de declarar el parámetro dinámico en nuestro método `createUser`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debemos pasar dicho argumento a nuestro método, para que efectivamente Flask pueda establecer la relación que queremos que exista entre el valor posicional de `id` en la URL y el valor de `id` a ser usado en el método `createUser`.

Ahora, en el caso que muestras, no tiene sentido dicho valor de `id` en la ruta, ya que estás apenas creando un usuario. Por lo cual el `id` aún no existe.

Mi recomendación es que elimines dicho parámetro dinámico para el caso en que estás creando un usuario (método `POST`) y lo uses solamente para el caso en que deseas obtener información de dicho usuario.

Por ejemplo:

```py
#crear usuario
@app.route('/user', methods=["POST"])
def createUser():
    nombre = request.form.get("name")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    result = db.users.insert_one({
        "name": nombre,
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    })

    return render_template("usuario.html", nombre=nombre, id=result.inserted._id)

# obtener usuario
@app.route('/user/<id>', methods=["GET"])
def findUser(id):
    user = db.users.find_one(id)
    
    # aqui se maneja el caso en que no se encuentre un usuario con ese id
    if not user:
      return render_template("not-found.html")
    
    # aqui manejamos el caso en que si se encuentre
    return render_template("usuario.html", nombre=user.nombre, id=user._id)
```

Como se puede observar, hemos eliminado el parámetro `id` de la ruta para crear un usuario y además estamos devolviendo el valor del `_id` del usuario al ser creado (¿sino cómo consultamos luego a dicho usuario si no sabemos su `id`?).

Además usamos otra ruta pero para el método `GET`, la cual si contiene un parámetro dinámico, que nos devolverá la información solicitada del usuario que coincida con ese `id` o nos devolverá una página de `not-found` en caso de que la búsqueda no consiga resultados.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota**

Recuerda siempre que las contraseñas no deben guardarse en texto plano en la base de datos. Siempre debes usar alguna función `hash` segura. También recuerda que debes corroborar que no existe un usuario en tu DB antes de intentar guardarlo.

Comment: Con lo que me has comentado se crea el usuario, pero cómo redirijo? Es decir, lo que me hace con ese código es crear el usuario y meterlo en la BD, pero no carga la página del usuario (que al final es lo que quiero), sino que se queda en el home, lo recarga.